# How to get content of subframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to retrieve all the HTML code (including head and body tags) of a frame that is inside an iframe (so my JS firstly connects to the iframe and then connect to the frame to get all the HTML code)? (All the pages are on the same domain.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what a 'frame inside an iframe' is, but if you want to extract contents from an iframe you can use this code:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("IFRAMEID");
var iframe_html = iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Replace `IFRAMEID` by the id you give to the iframe. If you are using jQuery, you can use the $-selector of jQuery to do the same:

```
var content = $("#IFRAMEID").contentWindow.document;
var content = $("#IFRAMEID").contents(); // Both are correct;
```

If you want to extract only the body part (or manipulate it), you can extract the body part of the document like so:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("IFRAMEID");
var content = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

Now you can use `content` to read the HTML or you can write to the `innerHTML` and manipulate the content of the iframe itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's .contents() function (http://api.jquery.com/contents/).